# heroku postgres 20 connections exceeded under low server load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Is my app doing something wrong, somehow persisting database connections too long, or is it normal behavior for the number of postgres connections to stay high even after an app's  subsides from a period of high activity to low activity?

One of my Heroku apps runs on the Basic plan (allows 20 connections), and while I was monitoring server activity using `heroku logs --tail` I was unable to connect to the console in another shell window using `heroku console`

When I ran `heroku pg:info` I noticed connections were pegged at the maximum, 20, despite the server load being very low at the time... a couple of concurrent users.

The only thing that was different was I had 30 minutes earlier fired up 2 web dynos and 4 worker dynos to monitor the throughput of running some email jobs with more workers. But the number of connections stayed at 20 afterwards.

Under very low load conditions, would the number of (often idle) Heroku dynos affect the number of database connections that are held open?

(Currently my server is back to 2 web dynos and 1 worker dyno and is experiencing moderate load - an email is going out, and people are clicking links. The connections is steady at 12... making me wonder if there is some guideline about how many dynos you can reliable run if your database is limited to X connections.)

Comment: Are you using an app server that forks off sub processes or threads that each make their own connection? You should consider setting the application_name on your postgres connection to see where the are coming from

Comment: It's a garden variety RoR 3.1.3 app hosted on Heroku cedar stack. Uses DelayedJob to send batches of emails.

Comment: @jpwynn how many workers are you using? Are you using Unicorn?